# TCP route binding to specific hosts in traefik

Tags: traefik

We are using traefik for simulating our production environment. We have multiple services running in kubernetes running in docker. Few of them are java applications. In this stack, a developer can come and deploy the code as per the git branches they are working on. So at a given point, we can have 100s of full fledged stack running. We use traefik for certificates resolution so that each stack can be hosted based on branch names and all.

Now I want to give developer the facility to debug their java applications. Its fairly simple to do it in java. You need to attach java agent while starting up the docker image for application. Basically we need to pass -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=37000 as JVM argument and JVM is ready to attach remote debuggers.

Now JVM is using JDWP protocol. And as far as I understand, it is a tcp protocol. Now my problem is: I want to traefik to create routes dynamically based on my docker service labels. That is also I am able to figure out. I used these labels in the docker service.

[image]

And this is how you connect to JVM remotely.

[image]

Now if in RULE, if is use HostSNI(*) then I cam able to connect to the container. But problem is when I am doing remote connection for debugging, traefik can direct my request to any container. And this whole thing won't work as expected.

I believe we must have some other supported function for TCP rule as well, apart from only HostSNI. What is your opinion on this ? Or Have I missed something here ?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I left the idea and gave up really. I told guys to open random ports with help of devops if really in need to do it and hardcode it in their stack. But I could not find a way to write a rule that shall route traffic to given containers based on rules like hostname. Basically could not provide a framework to them. Just did not work. By the way pretty interesting personal site you are maintaining!! :)

Comment: Yeah It seems like a difficult issue. I'm looking at ways to auto-write DNS rules. Thanks! Check out this template project for yourself! https://github.com/behoyh/AngularFirestoreK8s

Comment: I cannot help but notice; Is this your production key really checked-in into the repository ? Is this safe ?  https://github.com/behoyh/beshoyhanna.com/blob/master/angular-firestore-k8s/src/environments/environment.prod.ts

Comment: Yes, this is safe.

Comment: Please do let me know as well if you can work out a solution. Thanks & good luck.